# Did Martin Luther King, Sr. change his name as an allusion to the Semitic root M-L-K?

Tags: religion, names, civil-rights

Martin Luther King, Sr. was given the name Michael King at birth. Shortly after touring the Holy Land, he changed his name to Michael Luther King, and then to Martin Luther King. ([This source seems to be what other sources I've been able to find are based on](https://kinginstitute.stanford.edu/encyclopedia/king-martin-luther-sr).) This changes gave him the initials MLK, which is familiar to students of Semitic languages as something of a pun: the root M-L-K means “king” (מלך, ملک; no, Semitic roots are not that straightforward, I'm simplifying). It's possible of course that this was a coincidence, but given that Martin Luther King, Sr. was a minister, and that he had just been on a trip to the Holy Land (where he might have studied some Hebrew, if it hadn't studied it already), it seems like it might have been intentional.

Are there any documents supporting or refuting this idea?

**Edit:** Based on some of the comments, I believe it may not be clear that I know that Martin Luther the most famous Protestant theologian in history. Undoubtedly the “Martin Luther” part comes from that; that is not a competing hypothesis. The cleverness of any pun comes from its multiple semantic and phonetic associations. The question is whether there are documentary sources, closer to the event, showing that MLK, Sr. was aware of the potential for this pun. Examples would be letters that he wrote, or contemporary sources commenting on the pun, such as might suggest that the pun was understood and/or intended by MLK, Sr.

**Edit 2:** This has been a frustrating experience, but I'll just offer one further clarification for anyone who might be interested. This business about Hebrew/Semitic roots having particular meanings does not require the least expertise in the language. It's the kind of general knowledge feature of the language that would be covered in the first couple chapters of a book on Hebrew, or even in a course that touched only tangentially on Hebrew. (I believe my first exposure to the idea was in a course on Middle Eastern humanities, for instance.) So this doesn't require some obscure knowledge of Hebrew; it's a commonly discussed feature of the language.

Comment: ",Sr."? // Where does this idea come from? What has your research shown you? Like, about his Hebrew studies? Have you checked biographies?

Comment: More specifically, what's wrong with his WP entry that reflects also what's stated on https://kinginstitute.stanford.edu/news/commemorating-50th-anniversary-kings-berlin-trip namely, that after Holy Land he went to homeland of Protestantism, Germany, and _then_ changed names? If you doubt this often repeated story, (like foreword to _autobiography!_) please be more specific as to how you arrive at your theory.

Comment: This is the second time on this site I've asked for documentary evidence for a trivial hypothesis, and people have questioned the origin of my hypothesis, rather than providing documentary evidence one way or the other. It's a curious fixation people seem to have.

Comment: @adam.baker: *[**History Stack Exchange** is for historians and history buffs. (...) It **is not about: Questions answered by a simple Google search or to be found in a Wikipedia page**](http://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*.

Comment: Do you have a source in mind that a Google search or a Wikipedia page would have turned up?

Comment: As soon as 'Semitic languages' appear, the question almost always turns into something very nasty and racist. Unless, of course, you happen to be a post graduate student in those languages. Are you?

Comment: @Jos I was until I graduated. I strongly reject any suggestion of impropriety (or even of negative connotation) in the term “Semitic languages,” which is the accepted term—as far as I know, the only term—for a group of historically-related languages in the Afro-Asiatic family (Hebrew, Arabic, Aramaic, Akkadian, etc.).

Comment: @adam.baker Congrats. Tough subject, too difficult for me. (I barely manage Thai.) I see a LOT of people disguising their antisemitic rants behind 'Semitic' this or that. Makes one very suspicious. Hope you understand.

Comment: @Jos I guess you have that issue on history SE; not very common on linguistics SE...

Comment: If it were for me, I'd continue to ask for 'prior research' & try to make the Q more attractive to any possible readers. We don't know 'what you know', where you searched already or how you arrived at any hypothesis. We do not assume any poster to be always either lazy or uneducated, even if a post may look to many that it be the case. [We try to find a common minimal standard/format for questions to adhere to](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3841) so that the fuzz gets lowered, more readers interested, researchers engaged & answerers encouraged, to cut straight to the point.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Short Answer**

There doesn't seem to be any evidence for this. More likely, his visit to Berlin and sites associated with Martin Luther were factors, but there is no conclusive, documented evidence of this either. King Sr. himself said he choose the names of two uncles.

Nonetheless, although his autobiography makes no mention of him having studied Hebrew either at college or later in his life (though not during his time in the Holy Land), it is possible that he was aware of this *possible* pun on his name. I say *possible* because there are multiple possible meanings and scholars are by no means in agreement. Further, some of these possible meanings of MLK are not exactly positive. Consider also that the initials of many people can produce multiple possible alternative meanings, including unintended puns, so simple coincidence is a very real probability.

---

**Details**

According to this [Washington Post article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/history/2019/01/15/story-how-michael-king-jr-became-martin-luther-king-jr/), citing Clayborne Carson, director of the King Institute and editor of *The Autobiography of Martin Luther King, Jr.*,

> Scholars say there is no definitive account of why the senior King
> changed his name.

King Sr. himself said it was because he had uncles named Martin and Luther, and that  the change was his father's wish. Carson suggests that the trip to Berlin (including visits to sites connected to Martin Luther) during the rise of Nazism had a major influence:

> “It was a big deal for him to go there, to the birthplace of
> Protestantism,” said Carson... “That probably implanted the idea of
> changing his name to Martin Luther King.”...
>
> ...“But it seems likely he was affected by the trip to Berlin because
> that would have brought him in the land of Martin Luther. I think the
> obvious reason is Martin Luther sounded more distinguished than Mike
> King.”

In his foreword to the 2017 edition of *[Daddy King: An Autobiography](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=v_OxDQAAQBAJ&vq=europe&source=gbs_navlinks_s)*, King Sr.'s grandson writes:

> It is no coincidence that the greatest theologian of the twentieth
> century shares the name of the greatest theologian of the sixteenth
> century. Michael King was my grandfather’s original name, and Michael
> King, Jr., was the birth name of my uncle, but after traveling to
> Europe as a young Christian minister and learning of the philosophy
> and the protest reformation of the Christian church by Martin Luther,
> my grandfather returned to America and changed his name to Martin
> Luther King, Sr., and changed my uncle’s name to Martin Luther King,
> Jr., proof positive of the vision he held of himself and the vision he
> would plant inside his namesake son.

In his [autobiography](https://books.google.com.ph/books?id=v_OxDQAAQBAJ&vq=europe&source=gbs_navlinks_s), King Sr. makes no mention of Hebrew although he most likely had some exposure to it during his time at [Morehouse College](https://www.morehouse.edu/). His visit to the Holy Land, however, is unlikely to have afforded him much (if any) time to study Hebrew there. Unfortunately, King Sr. is not specific on dates but the The Martin Luther King, Jr. Research and Education Institute gives the dates [July 14, 1934 to August 10, 1934](https://kinginstitute.stanford.edu/encyclopedia/king-sr-tours-middle-east-and-europe) for his trip to Europe and the Middle East. As the group also attended the 1934 World Baptist Conference in Berlin August 4–10, there would have been little time for studies in the Holy Land (or anywhere else, especially considering the amount of time they would have been 'on the road').

Finally, as *LangLangC* points out in his comment below, there are several possible puns or other meanings relating to MLK. Possibilities include [Moloch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moloch), meanings such as 'to offer', 'to own', 'to rule' and 'to possess' and the word for 'sacrifice' in the Punic Language. In short, 'King' is but one many possible meanings of MLK, some of which he might *not* want to be associated with. You might find the etymology and theories section of the Wikipedia Moloch article to be of interest.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain? I have cited sources, including one well respected one. I think that my past actions on this cite have shown that I am open to constructive criticism and willing to improve my answers.

Comment: To round this off (based on latest edit: QP seems to dismiss the current content of this A?): Perhaps go into the many 'puns' possible to 'read' mlk as 'has deeper cross-linguistic/semitic meanings': malik, moloch, mamluk…? (this kind of artistic & poetic interpretative reading is _not_ what I'd support as 'reason for', but it's interesting in several dimensions.

Comment: No, I upvoted this answer. I haven't accepted it yet because it feels wrong to accept and answer that says there's no evidence—even if that is indeed the case, I'd give it some time in case an MLK, Sr buff is aware of further evidence. (My edit was not in response to this answer, which is perfectly appropriate and demonstrates understanding of my original question.)

Comment: @adam.baker Yes, it's always wise to wait a few days before accepting. I'm still searching but I doubt if I'll much more to be honest.

Comment: Personal note: the "no mention of him having studied Hebrew" is a bit astounding. I mean, some 'bible seminar' & everything downplaying this, or Greek, no contest. King-James-only & so on. But for any serious student to just dismiss the OT-language altogether? By way of not mentioned in that bio-book? Idk much about the person in Q, or his surroundings, but it would make me wonder indeed quite  bit if this would be really that easy? (I accept bio not mentioning it, but it seems strange to assume w/o further proof that he skipped a visit to theological variant of a  חֲדָרִים entirely?

Comment: @LаngLаngС Yes, I've been thinking about that. I'll be editing this shortly as he probably studied it at Morehosuse.

Answer (score 3):

> <sub>This answer attempts a [reduction to the absurd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum), by taking the premise for granted, regardless of its actual truthfulness, and then endeavoring to locate various logical incongruities inherent within its main thesis.
>
> Another viable avenue would be to boldly challenge the veracity of its underlying assumptions (such as the extent of King Sr.'s actual grasp of Hebrew, for instance, as suggested by **LаngLаngС** in the comment section below); however, this approach will not cover that particular line of thought, choosing to restrict itself merely to the former.</sub>

---

You are basically asking us to [prove<sup>**1**</sup> a negative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proving_a_negative), inasmuch as the internet, in its infinite wisdom, seems blissfully unaware of any such intent on King Sr.'s part. Let's start by stating the absolute obvious:

- His **surname** was *already* **King**; as such, what *meaningful* purpose would adding a (somewhat obscure) Hebrew pun *possibly* have served ? He himself took a a hands-on, practical approach to scripture (as opposed to pursuing a more scholarly path), surrounding himself with social workers and serving the poor and downtrodden, rather than academics and [Hebraists](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebraist), who would undoubtedly have appreciated such mystic anagrams.
- **Michael** the **archangel** is the **prince** of the heavenly hosts ([Daniel](http://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?search=michael+prince&version=KJV) 10:13, 10:21, 12:1). If **Michael King** Sr. would indeed have wanted a more **royal name** than the one he *already* possessed, why abandon it in exchange for **Martin** in the first place ?
- **Melchi**zedek, meaning ***king** of righteousness*, is a famous biblical character, carrying a very deep significance within **Christian theology**, inasmuch as Christ himself, the very founder of Christianity, is called *an eternal priest according to the order of Melchizedek* ([Hebrews 5-7](http://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?search=melchisedec&version=KJV), referencing [Genesis 14:18 & Psalm 110:4](http://www.biblegateway.com/quicksearch/?search=melchizedek&version=KJV)). As such, why change one's name from **M**ichael to **M**artin, instead of **M**elchizedek, were that to have been the intent all along ?
- [Malcolm X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malcolm_X), who oftentimes harshly criticized **MLK** Jr. for being too weak in his approach to civil rights, had his name changed to el-Hajj **Malik** el-Shabazz upon converting to Islam. With Hebrew and Arabic being both [Afro-Semitic languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Afroasiatic_languages), and Malik being the direct equivalent of the aforementioned Hebrew term, wouldn't such a choice be somewhat counterintuitive on his part, given his personal feelings on the matter ?

I'm not implying you're the only one to have ever suspected such a connection:

> The Hebrew word for **“king” is M L K (melekh).** Though **Martin Luther King, Jr.** was taken far too soon, all Americans should be grateful that **a King once walked among us.**
>
> *Rabbi Jeffrey N. Ronald*

— [Source](http://www.glensfallstemple.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/February-2016.pdf).

but, with *malak(h)* and *melek(h)* being the four most common ways of spelling out the [Semitic tri-consonantal root](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitic_root) MLK, the following **Google searches** should, in theory, reveal a wealth of relevant information on the topic:

- [http://www.google.com/search?q=martin+luther+king+"malak"](http://www.google.com/search?q=martin+luther+king+%22malak%22)
- [http://www.google.com/search?q=martin+luther+king+"melek"](http://www.google.com/search?q=martin+luther+king+%22melek%22)
- [http://www.google.com/search?q=martin+luther+king+"malakh"](http://www.google.com/search?q=martin+luther+king+%22malakh%22)
- [http://www.google.com/search?q=martin+luther+king+"melekh"](http://www.google.com/search?q=martin+luther+king+%22melekh%22)
- *feel free to use other spellings as well, such as* **malik(h)** or **malek(h)**, *etc.*

which, rather unsurprisingly, they don't (shocking, indeed!) — except, of course, for similar *ad hoc* observations on sites such as [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/5fud4u), for instance.

---

<sup>**1**</sup> <sub>History being, first and foremost, a science, proofs are — or should be — normative, rather than optional.</sub>

Comment: Or he could have simply changed his name to **[Malachi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malachi) King**, were he to have truly had such a fondness for the abovementioned Hebrew root.

Comment: 3 things I don't quite grasp from this A: 1. What is the actual extent of Hebrew studies MLKsr did? His actual knowledge? Christian theology after some level can't do entirely without, but it depends on that level (IDK for this case MLK). 2. Change from Mike to Mart to honor Luther1517 _&_ keeping _M_ (+initials on kerchiefs), adding 'L' to K? 3. The Melchizedek angle eludes me. Is it: Why not choose any name with 'M' (or any biblical, like you seem to suggest with Malachi)? That could benefit from clarification.

Comment: @LаngLаngС: **(1).** That would have been another good point of attacking the OP's logic; basically, my answer attempts a [reduction to the absurd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reductio_ad_absurdum), by taking the premise as true, and then trying to find holes in it. **(2)** Why even honor Martin Luther *at all*, if royal names is what he's after !? After all, the latter was just a humble peasant's son. **(3).** The *Melchi*- in Melchizedek, just like Malachi, etc. are all expressions of the same Hebrew tri-consonantal root **MLK**.

Comment: Well, in this case I would prefer 'check & challenge assumptions' instead of "attacking" anything (you know that SE users tend to be easier offended than regular folk ;) // And anotehr reminder: Will those explanations be lifted from comments into A-text?

Comment: I don't see how the question asks you to prove a negative. There is no request for a proof of any sort at all. It asks whether there is evidence. The possible answers to that question are, “Yes, here it is,” “No, but I've searched the following sources” (as Lars did), or “I don't know” (which I would have otherwise expected one to express by not responding at all).

Comment: @LаngLаngС: Done; as per your suggestion, clarifications have been inserted into the answer's main body.